# How to fade in/out images with different sizes and get a "good" result?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fading in/out images for a gallery.

My wrong result is this: https://www.3dexhibit.art/gallery.php?guid=a128d

I'm using jquery:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

How to correctly slideshow (using fade in / out ) different size images ?

Thanks

Comment: Make them all the same size?  Your external website is blocked for me (and no doubt others) and, more importantly will likely change (when you get it to work) making this question useless in the future - can you reproduce the issue in a snippet here?

Comment: have you tried using `.fadeOut(1000, 'linear')` and `.fadeIn(1000, 'linear')`? it seems that on your site easing is messing it up for you, try different easing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a container with x width and y height. Put a the same width and height as max-width and max-height on images and perhaps `object-fit: cover` or `object-fit: contain` (depending on what you like) on the images.

Answer (score 0):

Check This Codepen
[slideshow](https://codepen.io/md-amir/pen/mdJyrpB?editors=1111)

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
var index =0;
    setInterval(function(){
        var ss = $("#slideshow > div"),
            first,second,len = ss.length;
        first = ss.get(index);
        index++;
        if(index >= len) {index = 0;} // jump back to first
        second = ss.get(index);

        $(first).fadeOut(300,function(){
            $(second).fadeIn(300);
        });         
    },3000);
```

Comment: you have transition attached to all element thats why animations not working as expected add one line of css to your code and it will work as expected
div#slideshow * {
    transition: none !important;
}